# C++ - fail to modify pointer in class member function

Tags: c++, pointers

I defined a function getArray() in class A, like this:

```
void getArray(int * arr){
    arr = new int[10];
    arr[0] = 1;
}
```

I want to modify pointer arr in getArray(). And I invoked function getArray() in main(), like this:

```
int main(){
    A obj;
    int * arr = new int[2];
    obj.getArray(arr);
    cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

But when I executed main(), the output of arr[0] is 0, not 1. Why?

Actually, I want to allocate new memory to pointer arr and set the contents of the array in function getArray(). Then I want to get the contents of the array and deallocate pointer arr in main(). But I don't know what to do.

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do. Should `getArray` really *allocate* new memory and give you a memory leak (since the original memory will be lost)? Or are you just supposed to set the contents of the array? The answer to your question depends very much on this.

Comment: why are you using raw pointers and not some standard container? Are you familiar with references? pass by value? Why is the name `getArray` when it *modifies* the array? That seems like a very bad name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:  I want to allocate new memory to pointer arr and set the contents of the array in function getArray(). Then I want to get the contents of the array and deallocate pointer arr in main(). But I don't know what to do. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling `getArray` with a copy of your pointer.

You can call functions by-value or by-reference. Using a pointer may look like a by-reference call, yet it is a by-value call as a pointer only stores a reference.

You could use pass the pointer by-reference to achieve what you are trying to do: `void getArray(int *& arr)`.

BTW: I hope that this code isn't somewhere in a productive environment as it has 2 memory leaks.

**UPDATE:**

Examples using `std::vector`:

Example 1:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


struct A
{
    void getData(std::vector<int>& v){
        v = std::vector<int>(10, 0); //vector with 10 zeros
        v[0] = 1;
    } 
};

void printData(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << std::endl;
    for(int value : v)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    A obj;
    std::vector<int> v;
    obj.getData(v);
    printData(v);      
    return 0;
}
```

Example 2:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


struct A
{
    std::vector<int> getData(){
        std::vector<int> v(10, 0); //vector with 10 zeros
        v[0] = 1;
        return v;
    } 
};

void printData(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << std::endl;
    for(int value : v)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    A obj;
    std::vector<int> v = obj.getData();
    printData(v);      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You solve my problem! I will deallocate pointer arr in main(). Thx.

Comment: @user5566970 You do handle the memory leak correctly in your application, right? Have you thought about using `std::array` instead of raw pointers? This might make everything much easier...

Comment: In my application, I can only get the size of array in getArray() and the array can be large which costs too much memory. Meanwhile, I need to get contents of the array in main() and parse the contents to another function. Then I delete pointer arr in order to manage memory in main() after using arr. That's why I use raw pointers arrr. And I don't know whether 'std::array' can help me solve such kind of problem. Can you give me some suggestions? Thx :)

Comment: @JMAu That sound like a use case for `std::vector`. I updated my answer with examples. You should try the `return` variant first as it is less error-prone. Usually a compiler will optimize this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The array was not modified, because you reassign the variable in `getArray`. This code will work:

```
void getArray(int * arr){
    arr[0] = 1;
}
```

You should decide where the memory for array is allocated. If the answer is in `main`, then you should deallocate it at the end of this function:

```
int main(){
    A obj;
    int * arr = new int[2];
    obj.getArray(arr);
    cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

If the array should be created in `getArray`, then you don't need the allocation in main, and you should return the new pointer from `getArray`, and don't forget to deallocate it:

```
int * getArray(){
    int * arr = new int[10];
    arr[0] = 1;
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    A obj;
    int * arr = obj.getArray();
    cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` (as we don't use `std::vector`).